# Full BNF grammar for HL7 2.5

Tags: bnf, hl7

all I was wondering if anyone had a full BNF for HL7 2.5?  I am looking to compile this using the gold parser engine but would be happy to convert from EBNF or vendor specific BNF.

Comment: Have you tried looking around at HL7.org?

Comment: HL7 standards docs (from HL7.org) inlcude a very limited BNF description of messages.  I need a full lalr(1) compliant grammar that describes HL7.  Is HL7 LALR(1) compliant?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with what LALR stands for and Google is no help with the acronym, will you please educate me?

Comment: I found what LALR means.  I don't see anything that says HL7 is LALR compliant.  Sorry for the lack of help, you may be the first person looking for this information.

Answer (score 1):

The BNF description of HL7 message can be downloaded [here](ftp://ftp.ihe.net/International/Europe/HL7%20V2.5/HL7%20Messaging%20Version%202.5/Word/AppendixC.doc).

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of researching (which I am sure you have tried) I cannot find a BNF for HL7 v2.5.  I would recommend that you try to joing the HL7 community at www.hl7.org and see if you can push some buttons to get a more descriptive BNF designed.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty sparse and hard to get if you are not a member of HL7. The documents that you get once you sign up (and pay) are **pdfs** and the grammar is not easily ingested.

There are discounts for your affiliation with differing organizations. For instance, *they will call the AMA to check your credentials if you claim to be a provider*.

We have had to slow our HL7 rollout and implement only the messages as we need them, as opposed to simply having a parser chew out the schema.   It is clear that HL7 was made in a more 'golden' age of the Internet.